# Error 'clazz_ is not valid' using HQL createSQLQuery with Entity Class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an issue with Hibernate.  I'm trying to return a list of objects from my Database and need to join with a view that is not mapped in Hibernate.  So I am using the `session.createSQLQuery` method to create the query, then using the `SQLQuery.addEntity(Entity.class)` method to add the class.  Whenever I run this on my system I get the error:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name clazz_ is not valid.
```

Creating the query and executing (Note, the Employee object is being passed into the method):

```
String sqlQuery = "select * from company where company_id in (select company_id from company_authority_access_view where employee_id = "+employee.getEmployeeId()+")";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
query.addEntity(Company.class);
return query.list();
```

the HQL Output (This returns the values from the company table that I need):

```
select * from company where company_id in (select company_id from company_authority_access_view where employee_id = 1)
```

The query never contains a column 'clazz_' I'm unable to identify what's causing this error and have used this process with other objects and it works fine.  I've tried modifying my query to just use `select * from company` and this produces the same error, so it seems like there is something wrong with my object mapping, but I am unable to identify what.  The Company class uses annotations to map the columns the full company class is below

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="company")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Company extends OrganizationalUnit implements JobCostingSpecific, ITracksModificationUser, ITracksModificationTimestamp, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** identifier field */
    private Integer companyId;

    /** nullable persistent field */
    private net.company.model.data.Employee modificationUser;

    /** nullable persistent field */
    private String name;

    /** nullable persistent field */
    private String description;

    /** nullable persistent field */
    private Date modificationTimestamp;

    /** persistent field */
    private Map<String, CompanyProperty> companyProperties;

    /** persistent field */
    private Set<Division> divisions;

    private SortedSet<Division> sortedDivisions;

    private Integer version;

    /** full constructor */
    public Company(net.company.model.data.Employee modificationUser, String name, String description, Date modificationTimestamp, Map<String, CompanyProperty> companyProperties, Set<Division> divisions) {
        this.modificationUser = modificationUser;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.modificationTimestamp = modificationTimestamp;
        this.companyProperties = companyProperties;
        this.divisions = divisions;
    }

    /** default constructor */
    public Company() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Company(Map<String, CompanyProperty> companyProperties, Set<Division> divisions) {
        this.companyProperties = companyProperties;
        this.divisions = divisions;
    }

    @Transient
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return (companyId == null ? 0 : companyId.intValue());
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getCompanyId() {
        return this.companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Integer companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "modification_user", nullable = false)
    public net.company.model.data.Employee getModificationUser() {
        return this.modificationUser;
    }

    public void setModificationUser(net.company.model.data.Employee modificationUser) {
        this.modificationUser = modificationUser;
    }

    @Column(name="name", nullable=true)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="description", nullable=true)
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name="modification_timestamp", nullable=true)
    public Date getModificationTimestamp() {
        return this.modificationTimestamp;
    }

    public void setModificationTimestamp(Date modificationTimestamp) {
        this.modificationTimestamp = modificationTimestamp;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name="name")
    public Map<String, CompanyProperty> getCompanyProperties() {
        return this.companyProperties;
    }

    public void setCompanyProperties(Map<String, CompanyProperty> companyProperties) {
        this.companyProperties = companyProperties;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name="companyId")
    public Set<Division> getDivisions() {
        return this.divisions;
    }

    public void setDivisions(Set<Division> divisions) {
        this.divisions = divisions;        
    }

    @Transient
    public SortedSet<Division> getSortedDivisions(){
        if(divisions != null){      
            sortedDivisions = new TreeSet<Division>(OrganizationUnitComparator.LABEL_COMPARATOR());
            sortedDivisions.addAll(divisions);
        }
        return sortedDivisions;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + companyId + ")";
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see net.company.data.OrganizationalUnit#getChildren()
     */
    @Transient
    public Set<? extends OrganizationalUnit> getChildren() {
        return getDivisions();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see net.company.data.OrganizationalUnit#getParent()
     */
    @Transient
    public OrganizationalUnit getParent() {
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see net.company.data.OrganizationalUnit#getAccessibleType()
     */
    @Transient
    public OrganizationType getAccessibleType() {
        return OrganizationType.COMPANY;
    }

    @Transient
    public Integer getJobCostingSpecificId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    @Transient
    public JobCostingType getJobCostingType() {
        return null;
    }

    @ReportColumn(name="employeeCompanyLabel")
    @Transient
    @Override
    public String getLabel(){
        return LabelUtil.getLabel(this);
    }   

    @Version
    @Column(name="version",nullable=false)
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

The full stack trace of the error is below:

```
14:06:25,994 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:06:25,992  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:233 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
14:06:25,995 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:06:25,994 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:234 - The column name clazz_ is not valid.
14:06:25,995 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:06:25,995 ERROR AbstractCompanyDAO:799 - Error Retrieving List
14:06:25,999 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:06:25,997 ERROR companyRequestProcessor:496 - Error Processing Request.
14:06:25,999 INFO  [STDOUT] net.company.dao.impl.DAOException: Exception while getting authority access for employee: company Admin (admin)
14:06:25,999 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.businesslogic.security.impl.AccessRuleService.getAuthorityAccessForEmployee(AccessRuleService.java:830)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.ui.controller.masterdata.security.accessset.AccessRuleHelper.initRequestScope(AccessRuleHelper.java:80)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.ui.controller.masterdata.workorder.WorkOrderViewAction.execute(WorkOrderViewAction.java:109)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.ui.controller.companyAction$RequestHandler.handleRequest(companyAction.java:116)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.ui.controller.companyRequestProcessor.tryExecuteHandler(companyRequestProcessor.java:443)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.ui.controller.companyRequestProcessor.processRequest(companyRequestProcessor.java:208)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.ui.controller.companyAction.execute(companyAction.java:85)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:53)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:64)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:48)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:280)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:446)
14:06:26,000 INFO  [STDOUT]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:413)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.jsf.LeftNavTabFilter.doFilter(LeftNavTabFilter.java:44)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.jsf.companyJsfFilter.doFilter(companyJsfFilter.java:60)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.businesslogic.context.filter.companyContextFilter.doFilterInternal(companyContextFilter.java:72)
14:06:26,001 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
14:06:26,002 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
14:06:26,003 INFO  [STDOUT] Caused by: net.company.dao.impl.DAOException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.dao.impl.AbstractCompanyDAO.getList(AbstractCompanyDAO.java:800)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.dao.impl.CompanyDAO.getCompanyListByAuthority(CompanyDAO.java:184)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.getCompanyListByAuthority(Unknown Source)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.businesslogic.security.impl.AccessRuleService.getAuthorityAccessForEmployee(AccessRuleService.java:825)
14:06:26,004 INFO  [STDOUT]     ... 57 more
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     at net.company.dao.impl.AbstractCompanyDAO.getList(AbstractCompanyDAO.java:797)
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT]     ... 70 more
14:06:26,005 INFO  [STDOUT] Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name clazz_ is not valid.
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:625)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2218)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getInt(WrappedResultSet.java:698)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:61)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getInstanceClass(Loader.java:1589)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1431)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
14:06:26,006 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
14:06:26,007 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
14:06:26,007 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
14:06:26,007 INFO  [STDOUT]     ... 77 more
```

Comment: can you post complete stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Edited to include full stack trace.